# Confused about the existence of converse effect of Electrostriction

Tags: dielectric

In the research paper *(Alan Luna et al., Giant Electrostriction Response and Piezoresistivity of Emulsion Templated Nanocomposites, 2017)*, the authors mentioned that there is no converse of Electrostriction in contrast to Piezoelectricity which actually does have a converse effect. Electrostriction is the deformation resulting from applied polarization/electric field, but it is a quadratic effect unlike piezoelectricity which is a linear effect.

My confusion is that there is an equation in the same paper as follows:

$E_m = \varepsilon_{mn}' P_n + 2 Q_{klmn} \sigma_{kl} P_n$

where $E$ is the electric field, $\varepsilon'$ is the inverse of the linear dielectric permittivity in the absence of mechanical strain, $\sigma$ is the stress, $Q$ is the polarization-related electrostriction effect, and $P$ is the polarization.

The way I see it is that it seems there is a converse effect to electrostriction because in the equation it shows that a stress does give us electric field. I need to know the source of my confusion. Thank you.

By the way, there is a phenomenon called dielectrostriction which is the deformation/stress resulting from variation of dielectric properties and it is said to be something like the converse effect of electrostriction.

Also in another paper, (V. Sundar, et al., Electrostriction and Polarization, 1992), it calls the term $2 Q \sigma P$n as the converse of electrostriction. So, this makes me even more confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that stress can produce electric field, but it can't without polarization. So to produce electric field, we apply a stress, but the material has to be polarized. Actually if the material is polarized there will be an electric field anyway, but only that the applied stress along the present polarization will increase the electric field strength. And there's no quadratic relation in it. So, the equation doesn't contradict the fact that there's no converse effect to electrostriction.